# Css background fade issue with jQuery modal form

Tags: jquery, html, css

Better than the provide pasted html/css I thought a link would be better:
http://www.naughtyfancydress.com/html/index.html

Basically, I am trying to show a modal form popup on the click of "Themes" in the nav.

However, the background only turns pink for the area covered in the navbar div not for the whole page.

I've never encountered this before, is it because of the position relative on navbar?

Comment: I'm an idiot.  I just clicked that link at work without even looking at the URL.  Good luck with your question.  Someone else can answer it.

Comment: Sorry, its 12am over here but anyone else looking at this the link contains nothing x-rated but fancy dress clothing - cop costumes, halloween costumes etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pink `<div>` is a child of `#navbar` and `#navbar` has `overflow: hidden`. The result is that it gets clipped. Your pink `<div>` needs to be outside `#navbar` or you need to allow overflows (and possibly clear floats explicitly if you're using `overflow: hidden;` as a clearfix).

Comment: Please see your suggestion implemented, I would expect the whole page to be pink, this is with overflow removed: http://www.naughtyfancydress.com/html/mu-is-short/index.html

Comment: Almost there. You can move the pink-div up the DOM so that it is a direct child of `<body>` or some or top-level element (i.e. something whose upper-left corner is at 0,0) and then tweak the positioning, alternatively you can leave the hierarchy as it is and use `position`, `top`, and `left` in the CSS to put the pink-div where you want it.

Comment: @Mu is short - Excellent, now working. However, is there something inherently wrong with the html/css as a simple drop down menu over "Themes" doesn't work either (css/html was done by externals) - http://www.naughtyfancydress.com/html/mu-is-short/outfit.html

Answer (score 0):

noob ,

Have a hidden div like this

```
#VbackgroundPopup{
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    _position:absolute; /* hack for internet explorer 6*/
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:#000000;
    border:1px solid #cecece;
    z-index:3;
}
```

then on the click of the set the background like below

```
var docHeight = Math.max(

    $(document).height(),

    $(window).height(),

    /* For opera: */

    document.documentElement.clientHeight

);

var docWidth = Math.max(

    $(document).width(),

    $(window).width(),

    /* For opera: */

    document.documentElement.clientWidth

);

$("#VbackgroundPopup").css({

    "height": docHeight,

    "width": docWidth - 20

});


$("#VbackgroundPopup").css({

    "background-color": "#000000",

    "filter": "alpha (opacity=70)",

    "filter": "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(style=0, opacity=70)",

    "-moz-opacity": "0.7",

    "opacity": "0.7",

    "-khtml-opacity": ".7",

    "zoom": "1"

});

$("#VbackgroundPopup").css({
    "opacity": "0.6"
});

$("#VbackgroundPopup").show();
```

This should take care of all browsers...

Comment: I gave example from my code, you can probably change code to match your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the issue isnt not being able to display the modal form its the navbar css/html